# List of abbreviations/units customisation

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, fancyhdr, acronyms

I'm still working at my thesis template and ran into the next problem:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        \pagestyle{plain}
            \chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
            \begin{acronym}[SQL]
                \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
                \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
            \end{acronym}
    \mainmatter
        \chapter{Einleitung}
            Texttexttexttext \ac{SQL}

            Blablablablablabla \ac{Bash} and \ac{SQL}
\end{document}
```

As you can see first of the TOC, LOF, LOT and then I wanted to insert my list of abbreviations(/units maybe later on to) which worked really fine, but I wanted my explanations for the abbreviations aligned at the same line. Is there a way to `\hfill` it or put the same space between abbreviation and explanation.

And second question (I know only one is allowed, but it is the same MWE) is, if you take a look in the header, the `\rightmark` for my list of abbreviations still is the same as from the LOT. I'm sure I'm missing something again. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional argument to `acronym`, if used, should be the widest acronym, so the descriptions will be aligned. No automatism is available.

So, if you type

```
\begin{acronym}[Bash]
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\end{acronym}
```

the result will be

[image]

Complete example, with corrections for getting a right head height and a right heading:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[
  paper=a4paper,
  margin=1in,
  includehead,
  headheight=14.5pt, % <-- IMPORTANT
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
 {
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 }
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}}
         {\MakeUppercase{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\begin{acronym}[Bash]
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\end{acronym}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Einleitung}

Texttexttexttext \ac{SQL}

Blablablablablabla \ac{Bash} and \ac{SQL}

\end{document}
```

Sorry for the different indentation, but I can't stand it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works really fine and nice, but why is `headheight = 14.5pt` so important? I haven't got an error message in my log file. And I've got another question (I know I missed it) - is there a way to put some space and maybe dots between the abbreviation and the explanation?

Comment: @Chris.V There surely was a warning about it in the log file. To add some space, add a trailing `\quad` to the optional argument. Dots are surely not a good thing to add

Comment: Ah I must have missed that warning, but now I've seen it too. Ok then I'll not add the dots. :) Thought it would look kinda nice and saw it in some thesis too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `longtable` package:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{longtable} %It's here :)
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
                \input{Marito} %The file you have to input


    \mainmatter
        \chapter{Einleitung}
            Texttexttexttext \ac{SQL}

            Blablablablablabla \ac{Bash} and \ac{SQL}
\end{document}
```

and `\input` a file like this as your abbreviation list (this file's name is 'Marito'):

```
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\chaptermark{List of Abbreviations}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l @{\hspace{7mm}} p{0.8\linewidth}}

ADL             &  Activities of Daily Life\\
AST             &  Alternate Step Test\\
BMI             &  Body Mass Index\\
CSFT            &  Cross Step moving on Four Stops\\
DBN             &  Dynamic Bayesian Networks\\
DFRAC           &  Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
EMG             &  Electromyography\\
FEUP            &  Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto\\
FPRI            &  Fall Prediction and Risk Index\\
FR              &  Fall Probability\\
FRI             &  Fall Risk Index\\
GDP             &  Gross Domestic Product\\
GUGT            &  Get-Up-ang-Go Test\\
WHO             &  World Health Organization\\

\end{longtable}
```

If you want to add more abbreviations, just add them as another line in the table.  Don't worry about the table having too many lines, that's why you are using the `longtable` package: it will expand and will not harm the rest of your page configuration.

Comment: Works really well to, but for some reason I don't know, if I use my header I got a problem that it doesn't displays `\chaptermark` but "Chapter 0. List of Abbreviations".

Comment: It works for me.  please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, and @Chris.V, You should probabily change "List of Abbreviations" for Abkürzungsverzeichnis :)

Comment: Strange now it works. :) Yeah I already guessed, that I should change that. :D